# Logic of messageRead and messageWrite mode in microsoft office javascript API?

Tags: javascript, outlook-addin, office-js

Currently developing javascript based outlook add-in. When the add-in is launched, I want to open different dialog boxes in read and write modes.

How do I check if the add-in is in message read or write mode?

**manifest.xml**

```
<!-- Message Read -->
    <ExtensionPoint xsi:type="MessageReadCommandSurface">
    <!-- Use the default tab of the ExtensionPoint or create your own with <CustomTab id="myTab"> -->
    <OfficeTab id="TabDefault">
        <!-- Up to 6 Groups added per Tab -->
        <Group id="msgReadGroup">
        <Label resid="groupLabel" />
        <!-- Launch the add-in : task pane button -->
        <Control xsi:type="Button" id="msgReadOpenPaneButton">
            <Label resid="paneReadButtonLabel" />
            <Supertip>
            <Title resid="paneReadSuperTipTitle" />
            <Description resid="paneReadSuperTipDescription" />
            </Supertip>
            <Icon>
            <bt:Image size="16" resid="icon16" />
            <bt:Image size="32" resid="icon32" />
            <bt:Image size="80" resid="icon80" />
            </Icon>
            <Action xsi:type="ShowTaskpane">
            <SourceLocation resid="messageReadTaskPaneUrl" />
            </Action>
        </Control>
        </Group>
    </OfficeTab>
    </ExtensionPoint>


<!-- Message Compose -->
    <ExtensionPoint xsi:type="MessageComposeCommandSurface">
        <OfficeTab id="TabDefault">
            <Group id="msgComposeCmdGroup">
            <Label resid="groupLabel"/>
            <Control xsi:type="Button" id="msgComposeIndex">
                <Label resid="indexLabel"/>
                <Supertip>
                <Title resid="indexTitle"/>
                <Description resid="insertGistDesc"/>
                </Supertip>
                <Icon>
                <bt:Image size="16" resid="icon16"/>
                <bt:Image size="32" resid="icon32"/>
                <bt:Image size="80" resid="icon80"/>
                <bt:Image size="80" resid="paksign"/>

                </Icon>
                <Action xsi:type="ShowTaskpane">
                <SourceLocation resid="index-file" />
                </Action>
            </Control>
            </Group>
        </OfficeTab>
    </ExtensionPoint>
```

Answer (score 2):

We recommend using different SourceLocation URLs, or adding a query parameter to the URL, to distinguish between the different modes (i.e. `...index.html?mode=MessageRead`).

In your example manifest, this would mean using different URLs or query parameters for the `messageReadTaskPaneUrl` and `index-file` URLs.

While it is possible to check whether an API is defined to try to determine the mode, we don't recommend this because the API could be added in the future. For example, `Office.context.mailbox.item.from` was originally defined in Read mode only in API requirement set 1.0 (and `undefined` in Compose mode). But this changed when `Office.context.mailbox.item.from.getAsync` was added to Compose mode in [requirement set 1.7](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/reference/objectmodel/requirement-set-1.7/outlook-requirement-set-1.7).